# How to handle tracebacks when importing lots of content with Transmogrifier?

Tags: plone, transmogrifier

Sometimes it is convenient to "keep going" when importing lots of content, ignoring tracebacks and other failures that may occur with certain content.

Is there any generic mechanism in Transmogrifier to make this easier? The only approaches I can see are:

- Use only custom blueprints that try/except where appropriate.
- Use a wrapper to execute the pipeline that changes the source blueprint input to be one-after-the-failure each time.

Neither of these appear particularly convenient or desirable, hence my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you only need to write *one* blueprint which will handle and ignore all "tracebacks" you might want. be sure to put it right after "source" blueprint and yield in try/except block.

...

```
def __call__(self):
    for item in self.previous:
        try:
            yield item
    except Exception, e
        # here do with exception whatever you want
        pass
```

Comment: Got an example? I don't understand how this helps if I hit a problem later on in the pipeline.

Comment: This would probably be worth adding to one of the core transmogrifier blueprints.

Comment: for some reason code block are not allowed in comments ... so i updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that this is not a real workaround for that (common) issue, but here's my only solution: i use a lot of pipeline steps, each that make a single, well known, change to my items. If there's a step that i fear that can cause trouble i add a condition step (collective.transmogrifier.sections.condition) and simply drop potentially bad items. I think that a real solution could be to change the way the pipeline runner call each step, it should be responsible for managing exceptions in a customisable way. If someone else has a better solution i'm interested, me too.

Comment: I like the idea to use the condition section, that might be a decent enough answer.